# TypeScript: Create function wrapper for class constructor

Tags: typescript, types

I am trying to create a function that takes a Class and returns function that can return the Class instance. However, it provides type information only for the base class and have an error when I try to create an instance in `createFactory` function. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=21&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMDKAXA9gJwdA3gKGmgAcBXAIxAEthpKATaAXmgEYBuPAXzz1EhgDyAO2Tos0BAA8UCIXRjwIozNnyFSFatDDAUlNEIAUASlzRuBaMAMQUGErsyGNVGmABc0WxkpCA5gA0xOSu0GSeQiQAtmQIGKZqhF4kRHEmltwWAGYkQrr6QlZYYDIAYjpiAJ4APAAqEtKy8nCIqCpBAMINMnIwIgDu0IYAdKNgGH4QnmBClaaMAHzQtQuGHcUynh0JllgoJBiFI2MTU9AdNnYOYgAK42BRCDIYENUdC-NLA%20cbCMfD40mxg4FmsQls0AMCHKjgwlSYRQQJWhFUwlUMwmUWGBvEukJECKhMKqhgA5BBSUEAEw4qHDeh4OkVAomDhAA)

```
class BaseStore {
  public id = 1;
}

class OneStore extends BaseStore {
  public action() { }

  constructor(public a: string, public b: number) {
    super()
  }
}

function createFactory<T extends BaseStore, C extends new (...args: any) => T>(Create: C) {
  return (...args: ConstructorParameters<C>) => new Create(...args);
}

const oneFactory = createFactory(OneStore);
const one = oneFactory('s', 2);
one.id
one.action();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript can't really resolve conditional types that still contain unresolved type parameters. You could write the types in a different way:

```
function createFactory<T extends BaseStore, P extends any[]>(Create: new (...args: P) => T) {
  return (...args: P) => new Create(...args);
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=16&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMDKAXA9gJwdA3gKGmgAcBXAIxAEthpKATaAXmgEYBuPAXzz1EhgDyAO2Tos0BAA8UCIXRjwIozNnyFSFatDDAUlNEIAUASlzRuBaMAMQUGErsyGNVGmABc0WxkpCA5gA0xOSu0GSeQiQAtmQIGKZqhF4kRHEmltwWAGYkQrr6QlZYYDIAYjpiAJ4APAAqEtKy8nCIqCpBAAoNMnIwYEKVANoAugB8hgDCxTIRCADu0IYAdCtgGH4Qnh2mjKPQtQmWWCgkGIXLq+ub0NtMeyILUwglCBdLaxvGHBbWQrbQBgQ5UcGEqTCKzzKFUwlUMwmUWC+vBsKABInBgOBVUMAHIIDiggAmJGApb0PCkioFEwcIA)